# are there any open source shopping carts that integrate with quickbooks

Tags: open-source, shopping-cart, quickbooks

i am looking for a open source shopping card ecommerce solution that integrates with quick books.  I am currently hosting on windows IIS but would look at others based on suggestions.  is there any one that stands above the rest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use nopcommerce shopping cart, it includes most of the functionality

http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx